# uitableview reloaddata method blocking uithread

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using a UITableView which displays the users contacts. For some users with a large contact base (5000+ contacts) the tableview also has 5000+ rows.

The reloadData method in a democase with ~12k rows takes 100ms on the device.

Of these 100ms, the 'tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:' alone takes 30ms but actually is just:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(indexPath.row>50)
    {
        return 47
    }
    return 62;
}
```

This is due to the fact that it's called 12,000 times.

Is there anyway to speed this up?

Comment: Are you sure its the reloadData takes that long and not the actual reloading of the datasource?  Tableview doesn't load cells for all of the data it reuses them.  How are you reloading the datasource?

Comment: Check out the tableView:estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath: method in the docs. It was added to the api for just this purpose.

Comment: @Yan Yes, I am sure since I checked it in instruments.

Comment: @rdelmar No, it was added to give estimations for 'complicated' heightForRowAtIndexPath calls, the method is still called for every cell, as is the heightForRowAtIndexPath. So this wont help me, since my heightForROwAtIndexPath is really easy (contains just an IF and two returns)

Comment: Show your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath - my guess is you are not properly reusing cells...

Comment: @Mike Since I have checked my app in instruments, I found that cellForRowAtIndexPath is actually finished in 3ms, this is not the problem.

Comment: Perhaps you can humor me? If you aren't properly reusing cells, perhaps heightForRowAtIndexPath is being called far more than it needs to and that's why it takes so long? I'll do some testing locally to see if I can replicate it.

Comment: hmm looks like heightForRow is called for every item in your data source regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per Apple's UITableView documentation:

> "There are performance implications to using tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: instead of rowHeight. Every time a
>   table view is displayed, it calls tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
>   on the delegate for each of its rows, which can result in a
>   significant performance problem with table views having a large number
>   of rows (approximately 1000 or more)."

I would highly recommend a different implementation, whether that be limit your datasource to a smaller number and only augment it when needed (i.e. scrolling) or some other method.

I just created very simple similar code with 20,000 rows and logged when cells were created and when heightForRowAtIndexPath was called, and only 10 cells were created initially, but ***ALL 20,000*** heights were calculated ***TWICE*** before the view was even generated.

Comment: Hey, thx for finding that in the documentation. I think I have to find a way to make my cells the same size :/

Comment: Yeah it sucks, but that's likely what I would do if I were you especially given that the two cells are pretty close in size (only 15 difference...)

Answer (score 1):

Unless your cells have different heights or dynamically change just set the size and don't override heightForRowAtIndexPath.  The primary purpose of that is to allow each cel lot be a different size at the expense of taking time. But if your cells are all the same size it can simply calculate based on the stored value rather than querying each cell and adding them up.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I voted it up since you gave the right advice, but @Mike actually gave me quote from apple's docu and more detailed info, therefore I chose his answer. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Why loading all 500 Contacts at the same time ?
If it is to slow, just load the first 50 and if the user scrolls to the bottom load next items and so on.

Comment: This does not really help, since the problem in that case occurs when u scroll very very far down. It also is bad, since when the user starts scrolling very fast (which is possible for very long tableviews) loading 50 more wont help.